# Can't ping on windows

Tags: windows, ping

Whenever I run the `PING` command on my pc, It shows 'An' is not recognised as an internal or external program or batch file. And then it executes a dir command for `C:\Windows\System32` listing all the directories.

I think I've messed up my environment variables.
Here is the screenshot associated:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Then why not run `set` and look at the entire list of environmental variables and change the offender?

Comment: The ping.exe located in System32 is visible in the list of environment variables.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is very difficult to understand what you are describing in your post. Please take a few minutes to explain what the problem is, what you have done to try to resolve it and where you are stuck. Then ask a specific question. If you need help, read [ask] in the [help].

Comment: I think thats the best of explanations I could write for my issues and I cant embed an image too otherwise I would have done it.

Comment: Show us the environment variable you think you have messed up. What makes you think you have messed them up? What did you do to make them wrong? If you need to insert an image then post it to http://imgur.com and provide a link for someone else to move it inline.

Comment: I just modified the JAVAPATH variables three days ago as Android studio was not detecting them.

Answer (score 0):

As the first step, try changing the path variable.

1. Open up properties window (System Properties).
2. Open Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Advanced.
4. Click Environment Variables.
5. Select the PATH (%PATH%) variable.
6. Edit and see the values. Better to set it to C:\WINDOWS\system32, but it is not limited to. There can be others like C:\WINDOWS\, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0. You could separate these values by using a semi-colon.
7. It is also similar to SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
8. Examine other variables too.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest he backs up what he has on path before messing with it. Yanno. Cause he kinda broke it once already

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Well I found that ping runs when I run cmd as an administrator but not when it does not have admin access.

Comment: It would work when you use a different profile. On Windows 10, cmd still works regardless the use of admin elevation, unless you are not using an admin profile.